# Graphql request at Gatsby build-time doesn't send headers

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I added authentication between my front-end (Gatsby) and pollo. This works for request at run-time. However at build-time no headers are not send to Apollo. I have following code:

```
// SERVER SIDE
// apollo server setup
const { ApolloServer, AuthenticationError } = require("apollo-server-lambda")
... //other imports

const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: ({ event, context }) => {
    if (!event.headers.authorization) {
        // No authentication header
        throw new AuthenticationError("must authenticate")
    }
    // Authenticate
  },
  resolvers,
  schema: schemaWithResolvers,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
  formatError: (err) => {
    console.log("Error", err)
    return err
  },
})
```

```
// CLIENT SIDE
// apollo-client setup
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client"

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        onError (.......),
        new HttpLink({
          uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GQL_SERVER,
          credentials: "same-origin",
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Basic ' + '<login>:<password>', //works at run-time, not at build-time
          },
        }),
      ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  fetch,
})
```

```
// CLIENT SIDE
// gatsby-node (during build-time)
// => This call gets rejected during buildtime because authorization header is not available.
exports.createPages = async function ({ actions, graphql }) {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      apollo {
        allWathever {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `)
}
```

My apollo-client setup adds the Authorization header to my graphql request at runtime. But at build-time I'm getting errors because no headers are available.
What am I missing for the headers to be send during build-time? Or can I somehow detect if a call is triggered during build-time so I can ignore the authentication process?
Many thanks.

Comment: `graphql()` call in build time works in node env (separate things to run time server/client) ... directed to internal gatsby 'server', configure client separately for build or use some source plugin for external graphql api access, configure it, etc.

Comment: So I should add an ApolloClient on my server side? Right next to the ApolloServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @xadm I found out that to source data using to use at build-time you need to install a plugin and add it to your config. I use gatsby-source-graphql and forgot to also add the headers here.

```
//gatsby-config-js
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        typeName: "Apollo",
        fieldName: "apollo",
        createLink: (pluginOptions) => {
          return createHttpLink({
            uri: "your uri",
            fetch,
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
              Authorization: "your authorization",
            },
          })
        },
      },
    },
```

article about this: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/data-fetching/#fetching-data-at-build-time